# Change banner dynamically based on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I'm very new to rails and I want to have a banner that will dynamically change based on the page the user is on. Normally I would just have the banner image in the view for each page, however the client wants the banner to be above the navigation bar, and right now I have my navigation bar in my application.html.erb file. How would I go about doing this?

[image: Example of how the page is laid out]

Answer (score 3):

User a helper method.

In application.html.erb, in an appropriate spot, put something like:

```
<%= banner_helper %>
```

Then in a helper, define:

```
def banner_helper
  image_to_use = switch "#{controller_name}_#{action_name}" do
    when 'home_index'; 'homepage_banner.gif'
    else 'some_other_image.gif'
  end
  content_tag :img, src: image_to_use, alt: 'some text'
end
```